# Send email with attachments VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have been having trouble getting this code to run, the idea is that it picks up every email in column C, and attaches the file path in cell D1.
However it keeps falling over with error

> "Run time error 91 - Object variable or With block variable not set".

I have attempted to copy and adapt this code from https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/amail6.htm

```
Sub Send_WeeklyUpdatePack()
'Working in Excel 2000-2016
'For Tips see: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/winmail/Outlook/tips.htm
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim FileCell As Range
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim SourceFile As String
    Dim DestinationFile As String
    Dim strto As String

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Weekly Update Directory").Range("D1") = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Automation").Range("D22") 'Picks up correct filepath

    Set sh = Sheets("Weekly Update Directory")

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    For Each cell In sh.Columns("C").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
        If cell.Value Like "?*@?*.?*" Then
            strto = strto & cell.Value & ";"
        End If
    Next cell
    If Len(strto) > 0 Then strto = Left(strto, Len(strto) - 1)

        'Enter the path/file names in the C:Z column in each row
            Set rng = sh.Cells(cell.Row, 1).Range("D1") 'ERROR HERE

        If cell.Value Like "?*@?*.?*" And _
           Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng) > 0 Then
            Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

            With OutMail
                .To = strto
                .Subject = "Weekly update pack"
                .Body = "Hi all," & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Please find attached the updated weekly pack." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Kind Regards," & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "VBA Noob"

                '& cell.Offset(0, -1).Value

                For Each FileCell In rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
                    If Trim(FileCell) <> "" Then
                        If Dir(FileCell.Value) <> "" Then
                            .Attachments.Add FileCell.Value
                        End If
                    End If
                Next FileCell

                .Display  'Or use .Display/.Send
            End With

            Set OutMail = Nothing
        End If

    Set OutApp = Nothing
    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
End Sub
```

I'm relatively new to VBA (2 weeks) so an explanation/nudge in the right direction would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Set rng = sh.Cells(cell.Row, 1).Range("D1") 'ERROR HERE

Comment: So, you want the 4th column of the 1st row of a *Single Cell*?  Try `Set rng = sh.Cells(cell.Row,1).EntireRow.Range("D1")` or - even better - either `Set rng = cell.EntireRow.Range("D1")` or `Set rng = sh.Cells(cell.Row,4)`

Comment: the variable `cell` is not set to anything after the `For Each cell` loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I amended the code as below and it appears to run, although I am not sure why so any comments to explain what was causing the issue would be greatly apprecaited by myself and future readers.

```
Sub Send_WeeklyUpdatePack()
'Working in Excel 2000-2016
'For Tips see: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/winmail/Outlook/tips.htm
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim FileCell As Range
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim SourceFile As String
    Dim DestinationFile As String
    Dim strto As String

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Weekly Update Directory").Range("D1") = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Automation").Range("D22")

    Set sh = Sheets("Weekly Update Directory")

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    For Each cell In sh.Columns("C").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
        If cell.Value Like "?*@?*.?*" Then
            strto = strto & cell.Value & ";"
        End If
    Next cell
    If Len(strto) > 0 Then strto = Left(strto, Len(strto) - 1)

        'Enter the path/file names in the C:Z column in each row
            Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Weekly Update Directory").Range("D1")
        'Set rng = ThisWorkbook.sh.Range("D1")

        'If cell.Value Like "?*@?*.?*" And
           'Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng) > 0 Then
            Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

            With OutMail
                .To = strto
                .Subject = "Weekly update pack"
                .Body = "Hi all," & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Please find attached the updated weekly pack." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Kind Regards," & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "VBA Noob"

                '& cell.Offset(0, -1).Value

                For Each FileCell In rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
                    If Trim(FileCell) <> "" Then
                        If Dir(FileCell.Value) <> "" Then
                            .Attachments.Add FileCell.Value
                        End If
                    End If
                Next FileCell

                .Display  'Or use .Display/.Send
            End With

            Set OutMail = Nothing
        'End If

    Set OutApp = Nothing
    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
End Sub
```

thanks

Comment: `Set rng = sh.Range("D1")` should suffice.